# What MinGW version has std::condition_variable_any, std::thread and std::mutex on Windows?

Tags: windows, mingw

My MinGW version on my Windows machine that does not have std::condition_variable_any, std::thread and std::mutex so I am getting the following compiler errors:

```
error: 'condition_variable_any' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
```

I did a quick search and found this page https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases where multiple versions are available for Windows. What of them have std::condition_variable_any, std::thread and std::mutex? And what is the key difference between these versions?

Answer (score 1):

For best portability choose POSIX threads builds of GCC/MinGW-w64.

The builds from https://winlibs.com/ are usually built with POSIX threads, though GCC 13 also has MCF thread builds available, which are closer to native Windows threads and may also work for you.

Comment: What are POSIX threads for if I use standard C++ classes like std::thread, std::mutex, etc...?

Comment: When building GCC against MinGW-w64 there is a choice in threading models. The win32 model doesn't provide a proper `pthread.h` implementation (and the C++ classes you mentioned) as it uses Windows native threads. The posix model (and also the new MCF up to a certain extent) does provide it.